# Why can't I use the react-native style of styling in normal react?

Tags: reactjs

So, I've been coding react-native way more than react lately and I noticed I can do the react native style of styling things in react, what's the harm in doing so?

E.g
With react instead of doing classNames I can simply do

```html
<div style={styles.something)></div>
const styles = { something: { backgroundColor: "red" } }
```

What is the harm in doing so?

Comment: There's no "harm" per se, and CSS-in-JS (of which there are several varieties) tends towards something like this. It depends on how you're *actually* doing it; if it's scattered roughshod throughout the codebase it makes large-scale changes onerous.

Comment: I see I guess with that in mind and the performance issues that come with it it's not really advisable to do that I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way and it will work, but if you check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), its not recommended mostly for performance concerns:

> Some examples in the documentation use style for convenience, but
>   using the style attribute as the primary means of styling elements is
>   generally not recommended. In most cases, [className](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) should be used to
>   reference classes defined in an external CSS stylesheet. style is most
>   often used in React applications to add dynamically-computed styles at
>   render time. See also FAQ: [Styling and CSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

and this [section](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#are-inline-styles-bad) too

> Are inline styles bad? CSS classes are generally better for
>   performance than inline styles.